# How to select Image using jquery and upload it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to upload image using `jQuery.ajax` without a form.

I know how to select values for input boxes

```
var catSelect=$("#category").val();
```

But how do i do same for uploading a image (without making a form).

**Html:**

```
<div id="tnail"> 
   <input id="profile-image-upload" class="hidden" type="file"> 
   <img id="simg" height="126" width="224" src="'+tmb+'"> 
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
$('#simg').on('click', function() { 
     $('#profile-image-upload').click();
});

 $('#profile-image-upload').change(function() {
     alert( "Handler for .change() called." );  
 });
```

Comment: did u check this http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/upload/

Comment: without a form? AFAIK, even plugins will create own forms to submit data from input fields. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @dsuess then how do i upload a image using this code???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use
http://jsfiddle.net/Quwn6/

```js
  $('#simg').on('click', function() { 
      $('#profile-image-upload').click();
  });

   $('#profile-image-upload').change(function() {
       var formData = new FormData(this.files[0]);
       $.ajax({
          url: '/echo/json/',
          type: 'POST',
          data: formData,
          //Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I typed `jquery file upload site:github.com` on Google and found [**blueimp's "jQuery File Upload"**](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). It has been recently authored (2/26/2014) and has a lot of watchers. Hope that helps!

In [the FAQ for the plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions), it says:

> ### Does the plugin require a form or file input field?
>
> If you define the url (and probably paramName) Options, you can call the plugin on any element - no form or file input field required - and the drag&drop functionality will still work.
>
> To support browsers without XHR file upload capabilities, a file input field has to be part of the widget, or defined using the fileInput option.

You can also use `site:stackoverflow.com` to find relevant questions on here!

Have a good one.